# Listview id does not display

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

**listviewvideo.aspx.cs**

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Web;
       using System.Web.UI;
       using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
       using System.Data;
       using System.Data.Sql;
       using System.Data.SqlClient;
       using System.Text;
       using System.IO;
       using System.Configuration;

public partial class listviewvideo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Connection with DataBase
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Image;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();     //PostBack Function BindGrid()
        }  

        connect.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblFiles", connect);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds); //SqlDataAdapter ID
        listview.DataSource = ds; //Listview ID
        listview.DataBind();
    }

     //Upload a Video from Local system
     protected void btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)listview.FindControl("FileUpload1");
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length);  //Store the Video in to byte format
                string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        //Inserting the value to DataBase
                        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data) values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)); //Name of the Video
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", "video/mp4"); //Video format
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes); //Video stored in byte format
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }


        private void BindGrid()
        {
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString; //"constr" ConnectionString name used in Web.config
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();

                //Solution:1
                    //ListViewDataItem item = (ListViewDataItem)(sender as Control).NamingContainer;
                    //DataList DataList1 = (DataList)item.FindControl("DataList1");

               //Solution:2
                    //DataList DataList1 = (DataList)listview.FindControl("DataList1");


                    DataList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //Datalist ID
                    DataList1.DataBind();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

    protected void FlashVideo1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**listviewvideo.aspx**

```
         <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="listviewvideo.aspx.cs" Inherits="listviewvideo" %>

         <%@ Register assembly="ASPNetFlashVideo.NET3" namespace="ASPNetFlashVideo" tagprefix="ASPNetFlashVideo" %>

         <!DOCTYPE html>

         <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
         <head runat="server">
         <title>
               Youtube Videos
         </title>
             <style>
                    .myButton 
                    {
                            -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f5978e;
                            -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f5978e;
                            box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f5978e;
                            background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f24537), color-stop(1, #c62d1f));
                            background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f24537 5%, #c62d1f 100%);
                            background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f24537 5%, #c62d1f 100%);
                            background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f24537 5%, #c62d1f 100%);
                            background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f24537 5%, #c62d1f 100%);
                            background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f24537 5%, #c62d1f 100%);
                            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f24537', endColorstr='#c62d1f',GradientType=0);
                            background-color:#f24537;
                            -moz-border-radius:6px;
                            -webkit-border-radius:6px;
                            border-radius:6px;
                            border:1px solid #d02718;
                            display:inline-block;
                            cursor:pointer;
                            color:#ffffff;
                            font-family:arial;
                            font-size:15px;
                            font-weight:bold;
                            padding:10px 55px;
                            text-decoration:none;
                            text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #810e05;
                    }


                    .myButton:hover
                    {
                            background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #c62d1f), color-stop(1, #f24537));
                            background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #c62d1f 5%, #f24537 100%);
                            background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c62d1f 5%, #f24537 100%);
                            background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #c62d1f 5%, #f24537 100%);
                            background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #c62d1f 5%, #f24537 100%);
                            background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #c62d1f 5%, #f24537 100%);
                            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#c62d1f', endColorstr='#f24537',GradientType=0);
                            background-color:#c62d1f;
                    }

                    .myButton:active 
                    {
                            position:relative;
                            top:1px;
                    }

            </style>
    </head>


    <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">

                    <img src="youtube.PNG" />

                    <div class="thumbnail" style="width:13%;height:661px; background-color:white;float:left;">

                    <asp:ListView ID="listview" runat="server">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                    <div>
                        <table width="100%">

                            <tr>
                                <td> <%--ListView IMAGE--%>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image.PNG" Text="Watch Video" NavigateUrl="~/Wildlife.mp4" ImageHeight="100" onclick="Wildlife.mp4"></asp:HyperLink>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <%--ListView IMAGE--%>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image2.PNG" Text="Watch Video" NavigateUrl="~/Wildlife.mp4" ImageHeight="100"></asp:HyperLink>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <%--ListView IMAGE--%>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image3.PNG" Text="Watch Video" NavigateUrl="~/Wildlife.mp4" ImageHeight="100"></asp:HyperLink>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <%--ListView IMAGE--%>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image4.PNG" Text="Watch Video" NavigateUrl="~/Wildlife.mp4" ImageHeight="100"></asp:HyperLink>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <%--ListView IMAGE--%>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image5.PNG" Text="Watch Video" NavigateUrl="~/Wildlife.mp4" ImageHeight="100"></asp:HyperLink>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <%--ListView IMAGE--%>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image6.PNG" Text="Watch Video" NavigateUrl="~/Wildlife.mp4" ImageHeight="100"></asp:HyperLink>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                    </table>  
            </div>

        </div>        

        <div style="width:80%;height:680px;background-color:white;float:left;margin-left:30px;">

        <div>

             <table>

                <tr runat="server">

                    <td runat="server">

                        <%--FlashVideo--%>
                        <ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo ID="FlashVideo1" runat="server" Height="500" Width="1050"></ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo>
                        <%--FileUpload--%>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="myButton" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnupload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnupload_Click" CssClass="myButton" />

                                <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" Visible="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RepeatColumns="2" CellSpacing="5">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <%# Eval("Name") %>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

                                            <a class="player" style="height:300px; width:300px; display:block" href='<%# Eval("Id","File.ashx?Id={0}") %>'></a>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:DataList>

                            <script src="FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            flowplayer("a.player", "FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf",
                            {
                                plugins:
                                        {
                                            pseudo:
                                                {
                                                    url: "FlowPlayer/flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.12.swf"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        clip: { provider: 'pseudo', autoPlay: false },
                                }
                            );
                        </script>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
           </table>
      </div>
     </ItemTemplate>   
     </asp:ListView>
     </div> 
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

**Hi,
               -> I am going to display a image in ListView, For each image i had allocated a video 
               -> By clicking the image the video will play
               -> After that i am going to upload a video from local system using FileUpload Tag
               -> In this  ID is not displaying in ListViewVideo.aspx.cs, If i am removing the Listview the ID is working
               -> What will be the solution, i had uploaded my full coding, Help
Give me the solution**

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is an issue in the call-order.

Moving parts from Page_Load to Page_PreRender might help you out.
The call order in the Lifecycle of the page is as followed:

1. Page_Load
2. Event handling(i.e. your button event Handler)
3. Page_PreRender

You can look up the details about the event stages and the suggestions on how to use them under the following link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events